# Add VBox in InfoOverlay

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I'm using this very simple example of `InfoOverlay`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.InfoOverlay;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private InfoOverlay infoOverlay;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Node getPanel(Stage stage)
    {
        String imageUrl = getClass().getResource("/styles/duke_wave.png").toExternalForm();
        ImageView image = new ImageView(imageUrl);

        String info = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
            + "Nam tortor felis, pulvinar in scelerisque cursus, pulvinar at ante. "
            + "Nulla consequat congue lectus in sodales.";

        infoOverlay = new InfoOverlay(image, info);

        infoOverlay.setShowOnHover(false);
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(infoOverlay);

        return stackPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) getPanel(stage));

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I want to insert `VBox` or `BorderPane` into `InfoOverlay(image, info)`. According to the JavaDoc: Have only these default constructors:

```
InfoOverlay()

InfoOverlay(Node content, String text)

InfoOverlay(String imageUrl, String text)
```

Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't the constructor taking a `Node` do what you want?

Comment: No I tried this, it only accepts text. is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it only supports text. (The `Node` is the node over which the text is laid.) You will need to roll your own implementation (or [request a feature](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues?status=new&status=open).)